# Minus queries between HDFS and CASSANDRA having 70 million records is taking around 40 mins

Tags: apache-spark

My HDFS parquet file and Cassandra table is having 70 million rows and 16 columns and 14 columns are in Json with length more than 2000.

I am doing source minus target and target minus source. Then calculating count of each data frame of HDFS and Cassandra. All this taking 40 minutes for me.

Running on yarn with 6 TB space having 20 data nodes and 1640 cores.

Even if I am changing the num of executors to 100 and num of cores to 4 the performance is not improved. Please let me know if this is the maximum efficiency we can achieve.

Comment: Interesting question! Please do share memory and cores allocated per executor. Also, if possible share the code snippet especially the part where `minus` and `count` operations are happening.